# Flask view raises TypeError got unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a request to the following view. However, I get the error `TypeError: echoplaca() got an unexpected keyword argument 'placa'`.

```
@app.route(r'/enviaplaca/<placa>')
def echoplaca():
    return "Numero de placa: {}".format(placa)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You defined the route to be `/enviaplaca/<placa>`, but you defined the view function without the `placa` argument. The URL captures need to match the function arguments.

```
@app.route('/echoplaca/<placa>')
def echoplaca(placa):
```